# How to count text length on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I wanna create a class method to convert Article descriptions into Article contents (descriptions = 100 char from Article contents), I'm using LEN and doesn't work!

here we go my code:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :comments
    scope :has_rating, lambda { |rating| where("rating = ?", rating) }
    def self.has_more_than_100_char
        where("LEN(descriptions) > 100")
    end
end
```

I'll appreciate any help here.. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Using `length(description)` like this:

```
where("length(descriptions) > 100")
```